# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top class, not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Building out portfolio site using Bootstrap - I'm applying the 'navbar-fixed-top' class in order to get the navbar to stick to the top of the window, such as in this example:

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

I'm trying to do so using this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Contact Me</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

However, the navbar is still scrollable when I apply it to my own webpage. You can view the page here:

http://codepen.io/BenWS/pen/gmLEVw

Comment: Your link to codepen does not work.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Because you are using the newest version of bootstrap (bootstrap4 beta6).

They change from `.navbar-fixed-top` to `.fixed-top`

You have to read document in this [link.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#placement)

Comment: Yep! you are right. But why even `.fixed-top`  doesn't work on IPhone Safari?

Comment: If you want to have a fixed bottom, also omit the `navbar` as with ` fixed-top`.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is something wrong with the way your are loading in your bootstrap. Make sure you call jquery before you call the bootstrap files. If nothing works you could always add the fixed positioning yourself:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

working with bootstrap 4 on edge, firefox, chrome
 fixed-top without dot

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbarBGcolor fixed-top">
```